# AutoCompleteText with API Result android

Tags: java, android, laravel, android-volley, autocompletetextview

I have An `AutoCompleteText` in my android application that's take it's list from web services and my records in database going to be a big data like more than 100 thousands, and I can't do pagination because it's not going to give me correct suggestions, and i can't make a listener to do filter in web serves because it going to send too many request in less than second , what is the best way to do it , I am using laravel in server side and java for android and volley for API http request

Comment: Ask your sever guy to provide you top 10-15 items in one hit in corresponding of entered text.

Comment: It's impossible to download 100k records every time the user enters something in the text box. Do as @AnshulTyagi said and change the server.

Comment: @pskink about 10 records at time

Comment: @pskink I don't see any code , can you show me where ?